# problemas al conectar con base de datos de host

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

mi archivo de conexión esta asi

```
<?php
$server = "holahost.com";
$user = "MiUsuario";
$pass = "noTeImporta";
$bd = "sat_egras250";

$conexion = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $bd);
$conexion -> set_charset("utf8");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "No conectado", mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}
```

Cuando lo corro desde mi computadora
me arroja esto

```
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user 'MiUsuario'@'fixed-179-202-75-135.totalplay.net' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\m3u\config.ini.php:7 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\m3u\config.ini.php(7): mysqli->__construct('mochahost.com', 'MiUsuario...', 'sat_egras250', 'noTeImporta') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\m3u\config.ini.php on line 7
```

Esto solo pasa cuando estoy desde mi computadora conectando al host, antes si conectaba pero no se que paso.

El archivo también existe en el host pero ahí no tiene problema.
Trabajo con php 8.1.2 en mi equipo y en el host.
El usuario si funciona porque si corre sin problema en el host como les mencionaba

Nota: Cambie datos para proteger el servidor por si querían probar conectarse

Comment: Las credenciales del motor de bd estan correctas?

Comment: Tienes que revisar si están habilitadas las conexiones remotas a esa BD

Comment: @Antonio1512 Porfavor, edita tú pregunta cambiando las credenciales de acceso al servidor por cualquier otra cosa menos las tuyas... Le estás las credenciales de acceso a cualquier persona que lea esto... Te lo digo como recomendación para que no te lleves un sorpresa si te desaparece la base de datos por algún gracioso.

Comment: El error dice "access denied", tienes que darle permisos para conectarse desde tu host, tal vez tienes permisos solo para conectarte desde local(en el servidor) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html

Comment: @RuthIsRoot gracias bro, si le cambie los datos 

Comment: @OmarAlvarado ah ok, checate esos permisos en mi hosting

Comment: @Alfabravo creo que seguro es eso. Como migre de host este no recuerdo si lo configure. Gracias

Comment: te lo he editado para que te resulte mas seguro